# viewer node doesn't show up (even though I enabled node wrangler and pressed shift+ctrl+LMB)

Tags: texturing, node-editor, shaders

I want to apply a texture to my object in the shader. I need to connect my texture node to the viewer node.

I have the node wrangler add-on enabled, but when I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> on the texture node nothing happens. The viewer node doesn't show up. Does someone have the same problem and know how to fix it?

Comment: Hello :). Can you please mark the answer as accepted **✓**? This question keeps popping up as unanswered. Thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

Until you make it work, you can add the *Viewer node* manually :).

The *Viewer node* is just a renamed *Emission node*.
So you can add that, and it will have the same effect.

[image]

Comment: thank you soooo much!!! :) i really didn’t know i could do it like that

Comment: Happy to help :). Good luck with your project.